# SendGrid adding tracking information to emails

Tags: sendgrid, spf, shift4shop

**Edit:** Enhancement filed for SendGrid:  Ticket ID `#9192184`/Feature request `53`.

**Edit:** A workaround was proposed by SendGrid to use SMTP instead, but [Shift4Shop doesn't share their SMTP IP addresses](https://support.3dcart.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1059/1/), so customers must [disable IP address filters](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/ip-access-management#disable-ip-access-management) for this to work.

---

When sending emails from an ecommerce provider to sendgrid using DNS (MX, SPF), 3rd party tracking information (e.g. link manipulation) is being applied, and we didn't add it.

[image]

The explanation from SendGrid is as follows:

(for purposes of explanation, I'll use `ecommerce-test.com` as the domain we do NOT own)

> The account email is ****@ecommerce-test.com. Their settings have both **Click** and **Open Tracking** enabled, which is causing the link to wrap in the format that it is for tracking purposes. This one is tied to a parent account that appears to be the [... ecommerce test... ]'s main account. I hope that helps clarify further.
>
> I'm unsure you'll be able to make any changes since it belongs to another user entirely. But hopefully you can contact them for more information on what can be done for you. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

We did contact them... this is what they said:

> Thank you for using [ ... ecommerce test ... ]. We appologize that you are experiencing issues with your email account. Unfortunately, this seems to be a third party email to which we do not have any information nor access too. You would need to contact your email provider for assistance in this matter.

The raw `.eml` uses the following:
(for the purposes of explanation, I will use `test.com` as the domain "we" own)

```
From: billing@test.com
```

... however the email header has a lot of `ecommerce-test` information in it as well... here's a snippet:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
dkim=pass header.i=@ecommerce-test.com header.s=s1 header.b="...";
spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+27092108-7eb1-sales=test.com@em1876.ecommerce-test.com designates 149.72.197.132 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="bounces+27092108-7eb1-sales=test.com@em1876.ecommerce-test.com";
dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=test.com
Return-Path: <bounces+27092108-7eb1-sales=test.com@em1876.ecommerce-test.com>
Received: from wrqvcrvq.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net (wrqvcrvq.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net. [149.72.197.132])
by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ...
for <sales@test.com>
(version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 bits=128/128);
Mon, 01 Aug 2022 11:10:34 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounces+27092108-7eb1-sales=test.com@em1876.ecommerce-test.com designates 149.72.197.132 as permitted sender) client-ip=149.72.197.132;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
dkim=pass header.i=@ecommerce-test.com header.s=s1 header.b="QqJHti0/";
spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+27092108-7eb1-sales=test.com@em1876.ecommerce-test.com designates 149.72.197.132 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="bounces+27092108-7eb1-sales=test.com@em1876.ecommerce-test.com";
dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=test.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=ecommerce-test.com;
h=from:subject:mime-version:reply-to:to:content-type:cc;
s=s1; bh=...;b=...
Received: by filterdrecv-85d98588b6-9f6xt with SMTP id ...
2022-08-01 18:10:34.538903125 +0000 UTC m=+943491.816197811
Received: from 3dcwsvm311.sl.local (unknown)
by geopod-ismtpd-4-0 (SG)
with ESMTP id 45l4cBEuTbqvDbKf_4fk3Q
for <sales@test.com>;
Mon, 01 Aug 2022 18:10:34.303 +0000 (UTC)
From: billing@test.com
```

Questions:

- Is this a bug with Sendgrid?
- Is this a configuration problem with our emails?
- What's needed to remove third party tracking from our emails?

Related `[#OMZ-934-38940]`, `[#XYM-236-57661]`, `#9192184`

- Issue initially observed August 2nd 2022
- Issue was not present July 29th 2022

Comment: Hi, for those marking this as "Close - A community-specific reason " please help me improve the question by providing recommendations to improve it. <3

Comment: What's the ecommerce provider and how are you configuring SendGrid as the email provider?

Comment: The provider is Shift4Shop.  SendGrid is configured using these steps https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication as well as these steps: https://support.3dcart.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1023/1/how-do-i-set-up-my-domain-email-with-an-external3rd-party

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a long thread open with SendGrid support and have also opened tickets with Shift4Shop, and these may well be the best way to get this resolved.

As far as I can tell from the SendGrid thread, it appears that your email is in fact being sent out through Shift4Shop's integration with SendGrid.

One thing you might be able to do is [use your own SendGrid account as an external SMTP server](https://support.3dcart.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/514), so that the emails get sent from your own account with your own settings.

Comment: Thanks, a workaround is much appreciated. Shift4Shop does not allow customers to remove `mail.` records from DNS after they've been added (portal makes no warning of this) and I've confirmed with Shift4Shiop technical support that this will break SMTP.  I've escalated the removal of DNS to Shift4Shop's staff.  Once this is complete, I will continue with the SMTP configuration as instructed.   I'm grateful that you've provided this, as none of the other reps before (neither through SendGrid nor with Shift4Shop) offered an alternative solution to workaround the limitations of DNS.

Comment: I'm sure that the SendGrid reps, at least, were not necessarily familiar with Shift4Shop and I was only able to find that option from the links that you shared with me. Glad we could work together to get this fixed for you and I hope that Shift4Shop can remove the DNS records and free you up to use SendGrid the way you expect.

Comment: FYI, I'm still waiting for this DNS entry to be deleted by the ecommerce provider so that SMTP integration can be tested and deployed.

Comment: The DNS entry has been removed (I've been closely monitoring it) but the SMTP is still not working.  Since I've received no word yet from the ecommerce provider, I will assume that there are additional steps on their end before this will work.  If I do not hear from them soon, I will reach out again.

Comment: I still can't get through to anyone useful on the ecommerce side.   SMTP is definitely NOT working yet, the instructions from SendGrid couldn't be any easier, just fill out 4 fields, but when I configure my store for SMTP it just doesn't work.  Also, still no update on the status of the DNS records being removed (despite them being physically removed).

Comment: Ok, so I'm not 100% sure, but I think SMTP is a non-starter for Shift4Shop.  They [refuse to share their SMTP IP addresses](https://support.3dcart.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1059/1) so I think a whitelist is impossible.  This means DNS is a no-go and SMTP is a no-go.  @philnash do you agree?

Comment: Giving up on using SendGrid for the aforementioned reasons.  Switched to GSuite. :/

Comment: [IP whitelisting](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/ip-access-management) is a security feature that SendGrid provides, but it is not required. Your API requests are still secured by your API credentials, so there's no absolute need to throw the baby out with the bathwater here. On the other hand, if this is impacting your business go with what works for you. I would keep an eye on your email deliverability though.

Comment: Thank you, I dug for a while, but missed the https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/ip-access-management#disable-ip-access-management "disable-ip-access-management" portion of that article.   Thank you kindly for this information, I'm sure that'll work.   Apologies, I should have clarified, "giving up on using SendGrid [as a Shift4Shop solution]" is what I meant to state earlier.  We still use the JSON API for our bulk emails. <3. With this new information, I'll weigh and reconsider for the future.  It's been a long 7 days trying to turn these tracking links off.

Comment: What was the most confusing, and it was never resolved by Shift4Shop is that my emails continued to send through Sendgrid after all of the DNS settings were cleared and the site's cache was cleared.  Shift4Shop also informed me today that their own "bulk email" services that they offer through the portal use SendGrid under the covers.  I have no way of proving this (and the support on Shift4Shop side has not been very transparent nor helpful in understanding) but I have a sneaking suspicion that they have a bug allowing sites to fallback to their bulk SendGrid settings unbeknownst to clients.

Comment: Right, it seems that you thought you were using your SendGrid settings, but were, at least for transactional emails, using Shift4Shop's. Sadly, there's no way for me to tell why that was the case, and seemingly no way for you to get that information from them either. Sorry this has been a frustrating process. Hopefully you can continue happily using SendGrid as you thought you were from now on!

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the workaround proposed but also a warning about the need to disable IP filtering.